# Unable to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 instance with management studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed on my PC running Win 7 x64. I used to use it every day with a connection from management studio (Windows Authentication). But, for some reason, management studio is not accepting my connection anymore after I installed DB2 on the same PC.

I know that the instance is not broken since I am able to connect well with Visual Studio 2010 where I also tried creating new DB, inserting records etc.

How do I mend this problem with management studio? How might installing DB2 have affected Management Studio?

I am getting following error:

> TITLE: Browse Server for Database
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not an authentication issue, as you would get a different error.  If this is a named instance, you need to ensure the SQL Server Browser service is started.

I'm guessing you also have TCP/IP protocol enabled?

I don't know much about DB2 but maybe there is some conflict with the ports used.  By default SQL Server uses 1433 for the default instance, and 1434 for SQL Browser to dynamically allocate a port for named instances.  Check these to make sure they are still good.

Comment: +1 for resolving a similar issue I was having (browser service turned off)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have port opened on target server.

Use Telnet (install from Control Panel -> Turn Windows features On of Off)

```
>telnet <server-ip/name> 1433
```

or network scanner from [nmap.org](http://nmap.org)

```
>nmap -sT -r -n -vv -p1433 <server-ip/name>
```